# In selenium could not able to launch the chrome browse giving session not created exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/PrasadB/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I have followed these two lines of code

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'PRASADBALAGA', ip: '172.16.19.19'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:536)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:232)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at sample.SelIntroduction.main(SelIntroduction.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port.
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:518)
    ... 7 more
```

I am trying to launch chrome browser from selenium but chrome browser is not launching

Comment: The error says *Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port.* - the code doing this is not shown above.

Answer (score 1):

In the `System.setProperty` line of code, you are supposed to set the path of `chromedriver.exe` file. It appears that the path you have provided(`chrome.exe`) is for browser instead of browser driver.

**Correct:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win64\\chromedriver.exe");
```

**Inocrrect:**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/PrasadB/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe");
```

Having said the above, since you are using selenium `v4.11.0`, setting the `chromedriver.exe` path is not mandatory any more. Which means selenium will download and manage the driver for you. All you have to do is, remove the `System.setProperty` line from your code(see below).

```
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Users/PrasadB/Downloads/chrome-win64/chrome-win64/chrome.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```